# Como executar várias instâncias de uma imagem em portas diferentes?

Tags: docker

Tenho uma imagem `docker` que utiliza a porta `8080`. Para executá-la eu utilizo o seguinte comando:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e DB_URL="127.0.0.1:BANCO" -e DB_USERNAME="usr" -e DB_PASSWORD="XXXXX" custom-repo.com.br/teste:1-0-0
```

Gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa mas subir, hipoteticamente, 5 `containers`, cada um com uma porta externa diferente apontando para ele. Por exemplo:

- Porta 8080 acessa o `container` 1;
- Porta 8081 acessa o `container` 2;
- Porta 8082 acessa o `container` 3;
- Porta 8083 acessa o `container` 4;
- Porta 8084 acessa o `container` 5;

Existe alguma forma de realizar isso sem definir uma a uma?

Comment: Precisa ser em portas diferentes? Por que?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss porque eu preciso fazer chamadas simultâneas. Eu até pensei em usar um `nginx` mas o problema é que o usuário autenticado em um servidor não consegue fazer requisição em outra (usando `JSESSIONID`)

Comment: O Docker Compose possui a opção `--scale` que te permite gerar múltiplas instâncias da sua imagem. Será que ele não resolve seu problema?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss se gerar e eu conseguir acessar sem perder essa sessão aí acredito que resolve sim

Answer (score 3):

Bom dia Sorack,

Nesse caso, basta alterar no seu código a `porta` que deseja utilizar, como por exemplo

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e DB_URL=“127.0.0.1:BANCO” -e DB_USERNAME=“usr” -e DB_PASSWORD=“XXXXX” custom-repo.com.br/teste:1-0-0
docker run -d -p 8081:8080 -e DB_URL=“127.0.0.1:BANCO” -e DB_USERNAME=“usr” -e DB_PASSWORD=“XXXXX” custom-repo.com.br/teste:1-0-0
docker run -d -p 8082:8080 -e DB_URL=“127.0.0.1:BANCO” -e DB_USERNAME=“usr” -e DB_PASSWORD=“XXXXX” custom-repo.com.br/teste:1-0-0
```

E assim por diante com as outras portas.

Caso queira entender um pouco mais sobre expor `portas`, leia um pouco sobre o parâmetro `-p` ou `--port` nesse [link](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

E caso queira que o browser veja tudo da forma convencional HTTP, você precisa que colocar o proxy reverso na frente.

Comment: Mas assim eu vou estar configurando a porta 8081 para a 8081, por exemplo. E não é isso que eu quero

Comment: Acho que a porta do conteiner será sempre a 8080 xD

Comment: Apenas uma errata sobre o meu comando, utilize `8081:8080`, `8082:8080`